# External file changes sync may be slow: the current inotify(7) watch limit is too low

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, clion, inotify

The following message appears when I am running `Clion`:

```
External file changes sync may be slow: the current inotify(7) watch limit is too low
```

Neither of approaches [from recommended pages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Inotify+Watches+Limit) is helping.

What else can be done? How to know current `inotify` limit? How to know message threshold?

---

Operating system is Ubuntu 18

Comment: What Operating System/Distro are you using? What filesystem are you using? Which commands have you used?

Comment: I recommand https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/articles/IDEA-A-2/Inotify-Watches-Limit?_ga=2.129378376.570845270.1629710663-1914226881.1628070789